# Extjs inheritance odd behavior

Tags: inheritance, extjs

I have inheritance in Extjs, and I want a child class property to be merged with the parent class property (column in this case).

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Child', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.Parent',
    title: 'Action Column Child extend ',
    alias: 'widget.childpanel',
    initComponent: function () {
        //this merging very odd.        
        this.columns = Ext.apply(this.columns, [{
            text: 'Other',
            dataIndex: 'other'
        }]);
        this.callParent(arguments)
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/PM6j6/**

Two problems:
1) I am trying to merge the child columns property with the parent and the merge works partially, it added the `Other` column but removes first one from the parent. see jsfiddle for simulating.

2) When I render the grid and its parent and I click on the sorting, both of the grids are sorted. its like a collision.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you need to `clone` the parent columns and use `push` in this case:

   ```
   initComponent: function () {
       var clonedParentColumns = Ext.clone(this.superclass.columns);

       clonedParentColumns.push({
           text: 'Other',
           dataIndex: 'other'
       });

       this.columns = clonedParentColumns;

       this.callParent(arguments);
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/jUE8j/
2. Both parent and child are using the same `store`. (in this example a store is created for each one of them: http://jsfiddle.net/jUE8j/2/)

Comment: Thanks, your example does not add the `Other` field. and my question has 2 sub-question. thanks mate!

Comment: @Shazam: the `Other` field is added to the child grid.

Answer (score 1):

[Ext.apply](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-apply) is used to merge **properties** of one **object** to another. The grid's [column config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-columns) however is an **array** of column configuration objects.

Therefore you just need to push the additional column configuration object to the array:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.columns.push({
        text: 'Other',
        dataIndex: 'other'
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

As for your 2nd question, it was already mentioned that you need to use a different store if you do not want sorters and filters to be applied on both grids.